# Is there a way to disallow comments by default in EE3?

Tags: ee3, comments, default

Now that EE3 has done away with the idea of comments being a separate module that could be installed or uninstalled, the only way to 'turn off comments' that I can see is to go into each channel's settings and flip the *‘Allow comments?’* switch from Yes to No. Is there any way to make the default setting for allowing comments in newly-created channels to be 'No'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default setting is actually defined a the database level, so you can only change this on a per-instalation basis by altering the database table.

```
ALTER TABLE exp_channels MODIFY deft_comments CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n'
```

Comment: I would doubtless break All The Things if I tried that so, I'll just leave it as it is! Thanks, Derek.